# How do I debug step into an ASPX page that requires an XML request?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, file-upload

<strike>Is there a way to test sending an XML file as a request to my ASP.Net web page within Visual Studio 2008?</strike>

Ok, no one has answered this in a helpful way.  I have a situation where I have an ASPX page that I send an XML file too and receive an XML response from.  In order to debug this, I need to step into the page while providing an XML request.  I This is what I need to figure out how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. Just create an HTML page that contains a simple submit form, and it's submit action will post-back the XML. In visual studio, all you have to do is attach to process-> and choose the browser window containing your HTML form, and there you go.

Comment: I like it.  Alternatively, I could create a request from another page on the site that passes the needed XML instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a breakpoint at the code behind just before sending the file to see that everything at that point is as expected.

From then on, the best way to see what goes over the wire is to use a debugging proxy like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).

Alternatively, there is firebug and its `Net` tab which will show your requests and responses.

Comment: So Visual Studio doesn't have anything? Looks like, I'll be Message Box Debugging this. I don't have time to learn a tool.

Comment: @Jordan - Fiddler will take hardly any time to setup and use. It is worth investing your time learning something that can save you hours in MessageBox debugging.

Comment: Ok, Fiddler doesn't hit any or my breakpoints.  How does this help my situation?

Comment: @Jordan - Fiddler will show you _exactly_ what want on the request and response. This is, after all, what you asked about.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear.  I was wanting to send an XML to Visual Studio and step through the code of my web page in debug mode.

Comment: @Jordan - I see. If you have attached to the IIS process and put a break point in your web service, when you call it, it should break. Are you missing any steps?